# Is there a Chinese saying, ''even mosquito legs are meat''?

Tags: colloquialisms, saying

Is this the correct saying/correct wording of the adage? I've seen this a lot in machine translated novels so i'm not sure of the actual wording or if this is entirely a mistranslation, but i imagine it means to not look down on anything because even a small gain is worthwhile?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's 蚊子再小也是肉. It came from a 散曲 from Yuan Dynasty.

But it's meaning is slightly different than what you understand. It should be "even though it's very small/few, it's better than nothing". It's usually said when we want something but what we have is something of less amount/quality or something else that is not as good. We do not waste what is very small and it can at least soothe our demand partially.